# Git progress review branch

Tags: git, branch

I've been asked by another developer to push my incomplete code every day so they can do a code review on it. The wisdom of pushing temporary code to Git is better addressed on workplace.SE and that is not what this question is about. My question is how to do this while keeping my feature branch clean.

I've tried committing everything to a `progress` branch, but of course when I switch back to my feature branch, all the changes that are uncommitted in that branch are reset, including new files that I haven't tracked yet. If I use `stash`, it only keeps files that are already being tracked, so I lose them when I switch back too. So far, what I've done is move the head back while keeping local changes, then switching back to my feature branch, but this doesn't seem like a good method to me as the branches are then not in their proper states.

How can I maintain the same changes in two completely independent branches that should not share any history since being branched?

Comment: Have you considered cherry-picking?

Comment: But if the two branches will have the same changes, *why do you need two branches*? Also, what **exactly** do you mean by "keeping your feature branch clean"? If you mean "without temporary, unfinished, commits", then what I would do would be to keep "progress" *on top of* feature, commit your progress there, once it looks good, squash it and merge it onto the feature branch, this would move the feature branch forward, creeping along after the progress branch.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Why would you commit commented out code and `var_dump()`s? The point is that the two branches don't share changes. One contains garbage now, the other will contain good code in the future.

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. You started your post by saying you were asked by colleagues to push your incomplete code every day so that they can do code review. This is OK as long as these commits don't end up in your final branch, if they do they are going to pollute the history no matter what you do. Remember, **incomplete code is *incomplete code***. So if they want to keep track of this, and you have no clear guidance about how to manage this vs. your actual feature branch, perhaps you should ask them instead what would be acceptable?

Comment: This sounds to me like a moving target question, every comment or answer like "You can do it like this" will have "yeah, but have you thought about ...". If, on that other branch, you would do prototyping and such, I would still commit everything on that other branch. When you've reached a stable point, and code review doesn't highlight issues, clean up the code by removing commented out code and such, squash the commits and cherry-pick the squashed commit onto your feature branch.

Comment: Or rather, cherry-pick new commits on your temp-branch onto the feature branch (but don't push), squash the new commits and make sure they are good, then you can push this.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I don't know why you're posting comments, because I already worked out an answer and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if you add (stage) all uncommitted files, but don't commit them, when you do a stash, all these files are saved. After committing them to the `progress` branch, you can then switch back to your feature branch, apply the stash, and all files, including uncommitted ones will be restored.

#### Steps

1. On the `feature` branch, add all files but don't make a commit
2. Stash the changes
3. Switch to the `progress` branch
4. Apply the stash without deleting it
5. Commit and push the `progress` branch
6. Checkout the `feature` branch
7. Apply the stash

The working directory will now be exactly as you left it.

Answer (score 0):

once you have moved everything and pushed to the progress branch , if you want the changes in the progress branch back in your feature branch, then use

```
git pull origin progress
```

This will pull all the changes in the progress branch with the commit history.

Hope it helps!!!

If you want to remove the history , you can squash the unnecessary commits

Comment: You missed the point. The history must not be merged because there is code that should never be committed in the `progress` branch.

Comment: "You missed the point", since that requirement wasn't clearly stated in your question I'm not sure there was anything to miss. Granted, you stated that they cannot share any history, so merging (pulling) is out, but changes that should never be committed, wasn't mentioned.